# Elevation of GPS doesn't work

Tags: web, gps, elevation

I'm developing a website in which I'll use the elevation or the above sea level of the current location where it uses GPS. I'm testing a website where it will give the coordinates as well as the elevation.

The link of the website that I've searched and I'm testing: 
[MyGeoPosition.com](http://mygeoposition.com/)

PROBLEM: The elevation doesn't work on my laptop.

On my friend's laptop

[image]

On my laptop

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If it only works sporadically, the [elevation service used in the source code](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/elevation?hl=en) says it rate limits requests.